# Zend Framework 2 - Set prefix for form elements

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2, zend-form, prefix

I'm looking for a way to add prefixes for every element of a certain form.

If found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9796828/1331671) telling me that there is a `elementsBelongTo` option which I can use to achieve what I want.

Unfortunately I can't find any documentation explaining the usage. Does anyone know how I can use this option? And if it's still in ZF2?

And furthermore: I there a way to combine it with the nice `AnnotationForms`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if it will help, but instead of prefix you can wrap elements in form or fieldset with form/fieldset name.

You just need to have a name of form or set it and then use setWrapElements

```
$form->setName('some_name');
$form->setWrapElements(true);
$form->prepare();
```

from this point full name of element, for example 'password' will be "some_name['password']"

If you are using annotations you can use this with combination of ComposedObject.
It's very good explained here: http://devblog.x2k.co.uk/using-the-composedobject-zend-framework-2-form-annotation/

Comment: Thanks, great one. But my forms don't validate. Is there anything else I need to do within the action?