# Zend Framework 2 - Wrapped form elements cause validation to fail

Tags: php, forms, annotations, zend-framework2

I'm using a form which contains wrapped elements. The wrapping happens in the view like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15661426/1331671).

My action looks like this:

```
 $myForm = [definition here]
 $myForm->setName('entity');
 $myForm->setWrapElements(true);

 $request = $this->getRequest();
 if ($request->isPost()) {

        $myEntity = new Entity();
        $myForm->bind($myEntity);
        $myForm->setData($request->getPost()->get('entity'));
```

The problem: When calling `$myForm->isValid()` it's invalid. When calling `$myForm->getData()` afterwards it's empty.

I repeated the `setName` and `setWrapElements` in the action but with or without it, it doesn't work.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? The form definition is untouched and works for non-wrapped forms. So I guess the error is not in there.

**P.S.:** An echo of `$myForm->isValid()` returns an empty string. Is there maybe a way to get the error message? The form fields are filled with the data I've put in there and don't show any errors.

Comment: You can use $form->getMessages(); to get the validation messages

Comment: var_dump on this plz -> $request->getPost()->get('entity')

Comment: @AydinHassan: If you create an answer from your comment I'd accept it. it solved my problem after all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following:

`$form->getMessages()`

Will give you the validation messages.

You can dump the contents or loop the messages in a `foreach` loop. For example:

```
foreach($form->getMessages() as $msgId => $msg) {
    echo "Validation error: $msgId => $msg"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try to add line to your code, as I can see in zend's Form.php, element names aren't wrapped with 'entity' till the moment you call prepare();

```
$myForm->setName('entity');
$myForm->setWrapElements(true);
$myForm->prepare(); // << add this
```

But I don't believe that it will help, becuase behaviour you describe looks little different. Cau you show us more source code of Entity and var_dumps of things that Aydin and Sina wanted.

Comment: it was an error within my form. the `getMessages` solved the problem for me!

Answer (score 0):

In ZF2 data is not binded if the form is not valid. The reason because you see an empty string in the return of isValid is that the return type is a boolean, use var_dump instead.